# Editing war file with Midnight Commander

Tags: macos, terminal

I'm trying to edit the contents of a war file on midnight commander (Mac OSX). With a normal zip file, this works fine. However, when I try to open a war file, I get an error message:

> gzip: stdin has more than one entry--rest ignored
>
> Cannot open tar archive
> **filepath**/ugz://

This is probably some kind of configuration issue with mc. Any ideas how to resolve this?

Comment: I think issue introduced: https://www.midnight-commander.org/ticket/2891 request to fix: http://www.midnight-commander.org/ticket/2974

Answer (score 6):

Midnight commander tries to open war files as tgz files. Is should open them as zip files instead.

To fix this open "Edit extension file" in "Command" menue (F9, C, e). Search for ".war" and delete it from the listings. The modified listing should look like:

```
# .tgz, .tpz, .tar.gz, .tar.z, .tar.Z, .ipk, .gem
regex/\.t([gp]?z|ar\.g?[zZ])$|\.ipk$|\.gem$
<------>Open=%cd %p/utar://
<------>View=%view{ascii} /usr/local/Cellar/midnight-commander/4.8.7/libexec/mc/ext.d/archive.sh view tar.gz
```

Then add the following snippet somewhere in the file:

```
# .war
regex/\.war$
<------>Open=%cd %p/uzip://
<------>View=%view{ascii} /usr/local/Cellar/midnight-commander/4.8.7/libexec/mc/ext.d/archive.sh view zip
```